# How do I multiply values when using groupby [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pandas-groupby

I am using the code below currently to split the countries of movies and connect them with their rating. Then I use groupby to calculate the mean for each country. However, I would like to multiply the score for each country by the number of movies each has produced.

```
s = countryGraph[['weighted_average_vote']].assign(country=countryGraph['country'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*')).explode('country')
avg = s.groupby('country')['weighted_average_vote'].mean()
```

I have been stuck on this for a while now. Any help is appreciated :)

This is a sample of what results I currently get. I just need to calculate how many countries contributed to the average in avg so I can multiply each score by that.

[image]

Source of Data: [here](https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/imdb-extensive-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question by making a count for each of them.

```
 avg2 = s.groupby('country')['weighted_average_vote'].count()
```

Then I multiplied the count by the average (with a scaling factor)

```
avg = avg * (avg2 * 0.00005)
```

This gave me a list of all the countries (with no duplicates) with their average rating multiplied by the amount of 'weighted_average_vote'.